# Jailbroken , erased all data and restoring

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, restore

I have a 3g phone jail broken. In order to delete data. i click on the option of Erase All Content and Settings.

then i was stuck on apple logo when ever i open Iphone. So I entered into DFU mode in order to restore OS. But it throws me an "unknown error occurred 1015".while restoring ...

I dont remember the exact version i had on Iphone. before this mess. but i remember that done through changing the base band to Ipad.

I stuck , i am dont know how to recover my phone. Worried.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Erase All Content And Settings on a pre-3GS phone is slooooooooooooooow. In fact, while it is happening, only the Apple logo appears on the screen. (It may still be running)
From [HT2110](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2110):

> This process
>   can take several hours, depending on
>   the storage capacity of your iPhone or
>   iPod touch. During this time, the
>   device displays the Apple logo and a
>   progress bar.

Second of all, anytime you have an error message when restoring an iPhone, [TS1275](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1275) is your best friend.

> Error 1015: This error is caused by attempts to downgrade the iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch's software. This can occur when you attempt to restore using an older .ipsw file. Downgrading to a previous version is not supported. To resolve this issue, attempt to restore with the latest iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch software available from Apple.

Sounds like you want to restore to a more recent version, worst case just get the most recent jailbreak instructions with the most recent software that supports your hardware from the [Dev Team Blog](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/).